# What is the name of an operator $T$ satisfying $T^n=T$?

Tags: operator-theory, terminology

What is the name of an operator $T$ satisfying $T^n=T$?
If $n=2$, we say that $T$ is idempotent. But what about for $n>2$?

Comment: If $T$ is an element of a group $G$ with identity $E$, then if $T$ is order $n-1$, $T^{n-1} = E$, so $T^n = T$.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93:  Right!  And of course, with $T \in G$ a group, $T^n = T \Longrightarrow T^{n - 1} = I$ as well!

Comment: You are right, but the thing is that $T$ is not in a group necessarily. In fact, $T$ may not be invertible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operator is *cyclic of order $n$*. (There are three cases: (1) $T$ can be cyclic of finite order, (2) $T$ can be cyclic of infinite order, meaning that it is invertible but with $T^n \neq T^{-1}$ for any $n \in \Bbb{N}$ or (3) $T$ is not invertible, e.g., $T : \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}$ with $T(i) =|i|$.)

Comment: Hi @Rob Arthan, I thought the same until I found out that terminology is used for something else http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicOperator.html

Comment: @Chilote: Thanks for pointing that out, but I think saying "cyclic **of order $n$**" avoids any ambiguity with that other use of the term "cyclic".

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any special name for such operators, but they do all satisfy one engaging property related to idempotence:  if

$T^n  = T,  \; n \ge 2, \tag 1$

then

$(T^{n - 1})^2 = T^{ n - 1}, \tag 2$

that is, $T^{n - 1}$ is idempotent, seen as follows:.

$(T^{n - 1})^2 = T^{2n - 2} = T^n T^{n - 2} = T T^{n - 2} = T^{n - 1}; \tag 3$

so even though $T$ is not itself idempotent, it is closely related to one.

I guess you could call such $T$ an "$(n - 1)$-st root of an idempotent".